# Querying API returns unexpected response

Tags: python, api

I'm attempting to get average air quality data for a specific date from this open source dataset: https://docs.openaq.org/#api-Averages.

When I query the dataset using python using the temporal field:

```
import requests
import json

def jprint(obj):
    # create a formateed string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj,sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)

parameters = {
    "limit": 10,
    "temporal": "09/10/2018"
}

aio = requests.get('https://api.openaq.org/beta/averages', params=parameters)

jprint(aio.json())
```

I'm getting a response of:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "found": 3,
        "license": "CC BY 4.0",
        "limit": 10,
        "name": "openaq-api",
        "page": 1,
        "website": "https://docs.openaq.org/"
    },
    "results": []
}
```

I want to get the top city with the highest average air quality for the specific date. I'm not receiving an error but I'm not able to get the result that I expect. Am I somehow supposed to drill into the "found" field of the response?

Comment: The docs say `temporal` field must be one of the strings "day" or "month" or "year". If you want to use a specific date, you will need to use fields `date_from` and `date_to` instead. And date must be last 90 days.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. By the way the API was recently updated to allow for dates up to 2 years.